# How to change my database information in livecart after change database password?

Tags: php, cart

My livecart can't access after change the database password, but find the database config file , and found the message like this:

```
return
  'mysql://guaguaco_lcdb:.@RR?HbQ+CBQ@localhost/guaguaco_livecartdb';
```

What can I do to change the password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is inbetween the first : and the last @

mysql://guaguaco_lcdb:**.@RR?HbQ+CBQ**@localhost/guaguaco_livecartdb

Change to this
mysql://guaguaco_lcdb:NEWPASSWORD@localhost/guaguaco_livecartdb

where NEWPASSWORD is your new password

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I got another problem, the password is correct, but there is a lot error about the database error: `SQLException ERROR: Could not execute query [Native Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; `, the error page is [http://www.easy2u.com.au/]

Comment: Glad to help. Can't see that error page, if you're still struggling add a new question and paste the mysql error there.

Comment: Add a link to the new question here and I'll check it out